# Spring 3 AOP java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy43 cannot be cast

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I use Spring 3.1 and APO(proxy).

Annotation which was provided used as Pointcat. In this case Spring AOP proxy method "getMergeMappingsAndCals" was annotated with CalendarMappingAnnotation

My advise is AfterReturning

Aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MappingFilterAspect{
    /**
     *
     * @param retVal
     */
    @AfterReturning(
        pointcut="@annotation(...annotation.CalendarMappingAnnotation)",
        returning="retVal"
    )
    public void calendarMappingFilter(Object retVal) {


    }
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface CalendarMappingAnnotation {
}
```

Usage:

```
@Component
public class ApoiMappingManagerImpl implements ApoiMappingManager, ApplicationContextAware, Serializable {
    ...
    @CalendarMappingAnnotation
    public MergedMapAndCalsBeanCollection getMergeMappingsAndCals(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="...aus.aspect" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy43 cannot be cast to ...mapping.cals.ApoiMappingManagerImpl
[JVM ...]   at ...helpers.SaveFillRestCalsClientHelper.init(SaveFillRestCalsClientHelper.java:62)
[JVM ...]   at ...DispatcherImpl.loadPlugin(DispatcherImpl.java:426)
[JVM ...]   at ...dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.run(DispatcherImpl.java:181)
[JVM ...]   at ...DispatcherImpl.complete(DispatcherImpl.java:319)
[JVM ...]   at ...DispatcherImpl.process(DispatcherImpl.java:259)
[JVM ...]   at ...RunnerImpl.run(RunnerImpl.java:88)
[JVM ...]   at ...JvmLauncherSlave.main(JvmLauncherSlave.java:40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior looks correct.

It looks like you are casting an instance of a bean of type `ApoiMappingManagerImpl` and the code is throwing a runtime exception. The reason this is an expected behavior is because underlying you are using Spring AOP and Spring AOP essentially creates a dynamic proxy for you, this proxy essentially implements the interface `ApoiMappingManager`, internally composes the `ApoiMappingManagerImpl` and delegates calls to this composed class. So the proxy implements `ApoiMappingManager` and does NOT extend `ApoiMappingManagerImpl` and hence the error.

To fix it you should be if required casting to the interface not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

This kind of issue happened because I don`t describe this method in interface which was implemented by **ApoiMappingManagerImpl**

```
public interface ApoiMappingManager {
    public MapBeanCollection assembleMaps();
    public String getRootFolder();
    public void setRootFolder(String rootFolder);
    public ErrorList getErrorList();
    public Set<String> getAgentList();
    public Set<MapBean> getMappingSetByAgentName(String agentName);
    public CalBeanCollection assembleCals(String dateStr);
    public CalBeanCollection getCalBeanCollection();
    public MergedMapAndCalsBeanCollection getMergeMappingsAndCals();  // was missed
}
```